# Multiple docker-compose sharing network with a not yet known host for nginx

Tags: docker, nginx, asp.net-core, docker-compose

I use multiple docker-compose files :

- one for running on the same network : postgres and nginx
  => this containers collection is supposed to be always running
- one for each asp core web site (each one on a specific port)
  => this containers are updated through a CI/CD pipeline (VSTS)

Because Nginx needs to know the hostname when defining the upstream, if the asp core container is not running then it's hostname is not known, then nginx throws an error on **docker-compose up** command :

```
nginx            | 2018/01/04 15:59:17 [emerg] 1#1: host not found in upstream 
"webportalstage:5001" in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:9
 nginx            | nginx: [emerg] host not found in upstream 
 "webportalstage:5001" in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:9
 nginx exited with code 1
```

And obviously if the asp core container is running before, then nginx knows the hostname **webportalstage** and everything works fine. But the starting sequence is not what I expect.

is there any solution to start nginx with a not yet known hostname  in the upstream ?

Here is my nginx.conf file :

```
worker_processes 4;

 events { worker_connections 1024; }

 http {
sendfile on;

upstream webportalstage {
   server webportalstage:5001;
}

server {
    listen 80;

    location / {
        proxy_pass         http://webportalstage;
        proxy_redirect     off;
        proxy_set_header   Host $host;
        proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
    }
}  
}
```

And both docker-compose files :
**Nginx + Postgres :**

```
version: "3"

services:
  proxy:
    image: myPrivateRepo:latest
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    container_name: nginx
    networks:
      aspcore:
        aliases:
          - nginx

  postgres:
    image: postgres:latest
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=myPWD
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    container_name: postgres
    networks:
      aspcore:
        aliases:
          - postgres

networks:
  aspcore:
driver: bridge
```

**One of my asp core web site :**

```
version: "3"

services:

  webportal:
    image: myPrivateRepo:latest
    environment:
      - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Staging
    container_name: webportal
    networks:
      common_aspcore:
        aliases:
          - webportal

networks:
  common_aspcore:
    external: true
```

Comment: `aspcore` in the nginx docker-compose vs. `common_aspcore` in the core docker-compose config?

Comment: Yes it's particular but when you create a network with docker-compose the real network name is : directoryName_nameofyourservice so i refer the network as external in the aspcore website docker-compose with his real name. i try with only aspcore name network and i have a error like the network does not exist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally used extra_host feature to define static IP within my nginx+postgres docker-compose.yml file :

```
    extra_hosts:
    webportalstage: 10.5.0.20
```

And setting the same static IP to my asp core docker-compose file.
It works but it's not as generic as I would like

Answer (score 1):

Well, I use the following hack in similar situation:

```
location / {
    set $docker_host "webportalstage";
    proxy_pass       http://$docker_host:5001;
    ...
}
```

I'm not sure if it works with upstream, probably it should.

I know, this is not the best solution, but I didn't find any better.

Comment: Nginx doesn't  crashes if doinf so ? I mean even if "webportalstage" is stored into a docker variable ($docker_host), when resolving the line http://$docker_host:5001 on NGINX startup, it should leads to the same behavior than my error no ?

Comment: @Cladoo No, it's not. I use this workaround in some projects.

Comment: Great I'll try your solution